# Why did I earn reputation

Tags: support

I made a misinformed answer, and upon further investigation, deleted it. I made a comment on the existing answer to indicate what I had found.

Which of these actions would've earned reputation?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Maybe reference the question you commented on.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer had 1 upvote (+10 reputation), and one downvote (-2). You should have had 109 reputation, and then when the answer was deleted, everything reverted. As to why it showed the +2 instead of the overall -8, I am not sure.

Anytime an answer or question is deleted, everyone involved loses/gains reputation if appropriate. If there was no up/down votes on the answer, obviously no effect.